# Is it good choice to use JFlex/flex to write a lexer for YAML?

Tags: yaml, lexer, jflex

I'm trying to use JFlex to write a lexer for YAML, but found it hard, since:

1. Indentation is sensitive in YAML
2. There are multiline string like:

   ```
   longstr: >
     This is 
     multiline
     line
   ```

   is hard to implement.

I don't know how to determine and return correct token type for them.

I wander is it good choice to use JFlex? Or do I need some other tool for YAML?

Comment: I don't know if JFlex is the best choice there is, but I can't think of any reason as to why it would be a bad choice. Indentation and multiline strings wouldn't be that tricky to implement, from what I can imagine.